# Wood ceiling in bathroom

Tags: bathroom, ceiling

We are remodeling (actually, rebuilding) our bathroom in our 1930s farmhouse and when taking out the old ceiling, we encountered an old wooden ceiling with exposed beams.
This old ceiling we can't take out, because it forms also the floor for the storage space and bedroom above.

As we like the look of the wooden ceiling with the exposed beams, our plan is to create a slightly dropped ceiling from wood between the beams to have some space where we can hide the conduit for the electrical installation.

My question is, what advise can you give with regard to treatment of the ceiling(s) and/or beams to reduce/prevent the negative effects that the more humid conditions of a bathroom have on the wood.

Painting is an option, but then we would need to know if we should opt for regular indoors paint, outdoors paint or some specialist paint type.

For reference, our location is The Netherlands, Europe.

This is what the old ceiling looks like. Don't pay attention to the runs of pvc conduit, as that will be changed.

[image: wood ceiling with exposed beams]
[image: wood ceiling sloping]

Comment: **Have** an exhaust fan, **use** the exhaust fan, enjoy your ceiling. Consider the typical sauna - raw wood, hot/dry, hot/humid, manages just fine.

Comment: Hi fellow Dutchman!    I'm not going to post this as an answer because I think my comment is fairly opinion based.  That said:  I'd lean toward a solid surface finish like Varathane or Urethane rather than a penetrating finish like oil.  Others may have a different opinion As you remodel, I hop you are putting in a high capacity ventilation fan (extractor fan as our Brit friends would say).

Comment: You have a very strong potential to leave the ceiling intact with no consequences, but a few pictures would give an insight how to give better answers.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this ceiling appeared after you have removed another old ceiling beneath, so originally there was a space in between the two ceilings. Apparently, either the space was well ventilated, or the wood was treated. You should investigate more to determine what is truly required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plan is good, creating a space for the wiring, etc. to pass overhead in the ceiling, and cover it up with a new layer of finish will help keep the things that might settle through the cracks from the upstairs from dropping through. Do make sure the wires are protected from the potential of being pierced by nails or screws.

You should not need any special consideration on the type of paint. No more than what would be considered anyway... a good quality paint. In any bathroom, whether it is new or old or remodeled, has never needed an exterior paint. Preparation is everything. If the prep work is not done properly, your new paint layer may fail.

Answer (score -2):

I remember them wooden ceilings, they were down the lane. What you want is a suspended ceiling AKA drop ceiling. A suspended ceiling typically uses a metal grid that supports although lath strips can also be used and is supported by the joists above to hold the tiles.  You can use several different types of
tiles such as  plastic, polystyrene or vinyl tiles that are resistant to mold and mildew. This is available at your favorite box store.